# Using CLion and PyCharm simultaneously

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, clion, project-structure

I am using CLion and PyCharm at the same time on one project. If I switch from CLion to PyCharm or vice versa I encounter the following message:

```
Project components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:

ToolWindowManager
FileEditorManager
editorHistoryManager

Would you like to reload project?
```

I noticed my source Directories were revoked every time I switched to PyCharm. This is a problem since I need those Directories to be marked as source to have them automatically included in the Python path variable which is configured as run configuration.

Reloading the project is time consuming (especially with C++ code).
Are there ways to avoid reloading or even encountering this message at all?

I am using CLion 1.2.2 and Pycharm 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Are both IDEs sharing the same project settings directory (usually named `.idea`)?  If so, you might want to switch one of them to use a different directory.  Both PyCharm and CLion are built on top of the IntelliJ IDE infrastructure, so they are probably stomping on each other's internal state if they're sharing the same `.idea` directory.

Comment: I was searching Google, but I did not mange to find a "how-to" guide. How do you change the project settings directory for a single project in PyCharm or CLion?

Comment: It seems this is not possible directly. However there is a workaround which you can find here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from January 2016, the CLion 1.5 EAP series have Python support built-in, so you can use CLion both for C++ and Python, no need for PyCharm anymore :-)

Check out http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/python-support-in-clion/ for details.